# Select.Autofill Destination:=Range NOT autofilling

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working with VBA for about two years now, and I am having a problem I haven't had before. I am trying to autofill columns A, B, D, E and G with formulas based on the number of cells that are populated in column L. In the example shown below, cells L2-L5 are populated. With my autofill formulas, this should mean that cells A2-A5 populate, cells B2-B5 populate etc. But they don't. Only column G populates correctly, and I am stumped as to why this is happening. Any brilliant ideas?

Here is my code:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets("QBTimecard").Select
    Range("DP2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=RC[-119]&""_""&RC[-107]&""_""&IF(RC[-2]<>""Client Transportation"",""Z"",""XY"")"
    Range("DQ2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-13]<=RC[-8],""Pass"",""MMV"")"
    On Error Resume Next
    Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("dp2:ds" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

Sheets("QBTimecard").Select
    Columns("DP:DP").Select
    Selection.Copy
Sheets("PunchEntryImport").Select
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Range("L1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Blank"
    Range("L2").Select

 Sheets("PunchEntryImport").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(QBTimecard!C,MATCH(PunchEntryImport!RC[11],QBTimecard!C[119],0))"
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIF(QBTimecard!C[118],PunchEntryImport!RC[10],QBTimecard!C[13])/COUNTIF(QBTimecard!C[118],PunchEntryImport!RC[10])"
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(Lookup!C[-2],MATCH(INDEX(QBTimecard!C[9],MATCH(PunchEntryImport!RC[8],QBTimecard!C[116],0)),Lookup!C[-3],0))&""/1/""&INDEX(QBTimecard!C[10],MATCH(PunchEntryImport!RC[8],QBTimecard!C[116],0))&"" ""&TEXT(INDEX(QBTimecard!C[12],MATCH(PunchEntryImport!RC[8],QBTimecard!C[116],0)),""HHMM"")"
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(Lookup!C[-3],MATCH(INDEX(QBTimecard!C[8],MATCH(PunchEntryImport!RC[7],QBTimecard!C[115],0)),Lookup!C[-4],0))&""/1/""&INDEX(QBTimecard!C[9],MATCH(PunchEntryImport!RC[7],QBTimecard!C[115],0))&"" ""&TEXT(INDEX(QBTimecard!C[12],MATCH(PunchEntryImport!RC[7],QBTimecard!C[115],0)),""HHMM"")"
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=INDEX(QBTimecard!C[103],MATCH(PunchEntryImport!RC[5],QBTimecard!C[113],0))"
   On Error Resume Next

'This is the portion that is not autofilling   
   Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("a2:a" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)
   Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("b2:b" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)
   Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("d2:d" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)
   Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("e2:e" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)
   Selection.Autofill Destination:=Range("g2:g" & Cells(Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the help for [Range.AutoFill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofill)

> The destination must include the source range.

Because you are using `Selection.AutoFill` and G2 is the active cell, the autofill will only work when G2 is part of the range being autofilled.

To fix this, replace `Selection.AutoFill` with `Range("A2").AutoFill`, `Range("B2").AutoFill` and so on

Comment: Duh! I feel so silly. Thanks so much for your help, @borrowc!

Answer (score 3):

Without re-writing the whole thing, this is a more-approachable way to handle this, without the Select/ Activate/ Autofill:

```vb
Dim wsQBTC As Worksheet, wsPE As Worksheet, lr As Long

Set wsQBTC = Worksheets("QBTimecard")
Set wsPEI = Worksheets("PunchEntryImport")

lr = wsQBTC.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
With wsQBTC
    .Range("DP2:DP" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-119]&""_""&RC[-107]&""_""&IF(RC[-2]<>""Client Transportation"",""Z"",""XY"")"
    .Range("DQ2:DQ" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-13]<=RC[-8],""Pass"",""MMV"")"
End With
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Tim Williams! I used barrowc's suggestion and it worked.